# Spring MVC Hibernate One to One Cascade.ALL merge() Issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Using Spring MVC + Hibernate, I want to perform a CRUD operation on `Employee` entity.

The `employee` entity has a one to one relationship with `user` entity as shown below:

[image]

I'm having issue while updating the employee information. `CREATE`, `READ` and `DELETE` operations are working fine.

But when I update the employee information, it deletes the record from `employee_user` table breaking the relationship between the employee and corresponding user.

I have a single `JSP` page to save the employee and user information.

JSP:

```
<form:form action="save" method="post" commandName="employee"">
    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">Name: </label>
            <form:input id="firstName" path="firstName" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <form:input id="email" path="email" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
            <form:input id="phone" path="phone" type="text" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="usernmae">Username: </label>
            <form:input id="username" path="user.username" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <form:input id="password" path="user.password" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <form:input path="id" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="user.id" type="hidden" />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form:form>
```

The Employee model is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String phone;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_user", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL })
    private User user;

    // getters and setters

}
```

And the `USER` model is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_user", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL })
    private Employee employee;

    // getters and setters

}
```

The controller section is as follows. The same method handles both CREATE and UPDATE request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
        BindingResult result) {

    employeeService.save(employee);
    return "";
}
```

Here, the save method call the Hibernate's `Session.merge(employee);` method.

Can anyone let me know what's the issue behind the scene?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you show the `save` method of `EmployeeService`? Also, if you update the entity in a standalone application (yourself creating  sessions, etc.), works ok?

Comment: Hello Bruno, the service methods doesn't do any modifications. It simply calls the persistence layer method which in turn simply saves the entity using merge() method as stated in the question.

Comment: Ok, fine. And in the persistence layer, only calls `merge` method, that is? Without spring, just calling `merge` method, works or not (of course with "equal" objects)? Anyway I'll try to reproduce this. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Bruno, yeah look like, it's working without Spring. Fetched an employee record from db, updated employee info and even the user info and then called session.merge(employee). It works fine. So what could be the way out to this? Any modifications needed on the JSP? or I could simply update controller to have a separate method to handle update, where I can retrieve existing employee from DB and update the field in the persistent object from the command object. But I believe there must be some other ways around. Thanks Bruno.

Comment: [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) is configured in `web.xml` or you are using another approach? And, in the persistence layer, how you decide between `Session.merge` and `Session.save`? Sorry for the many questions, but it's for try to see what can be your problem =)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is that your ModelAttribute employee object  will be override with the new values from the Form .So , Treat  the user object Null .you can search the employee from database by id  ,then , set the user from the employee searched .finally, merge employee object.